# Can I run a function after useMemo return is on the screen

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-usememo

I'd like to get some kind of call back once `memoizedTodos` are displayed on the screen.

or execute `handleOpen` function once `memoizedTodos` are displayed on the screen.

Right now what I'm displaying on the screen is just the text. but you could imagine that this useMemo returns thousands of texts and images so it will take a while for those to be on the screen.

What I want to do here is run the `handleOpen` function after memoizedTodos returns are displayed like I can see all the todos visibly on the screen.

Are there any way that I can do this?

I thought I could use `async/await` to do this? or what would it be the best way to do this?

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const handleOpen = () => {
    console.log("this is running");
  };

   const memoizedTodos = useMemo(() => {
    return [...Array(n)].map((e, i) => <li key={i}>This is so many data</li>);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <>{memoizedTodos}</>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can't use async / await here. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Okay I can't use async/await here. So technically I don't have to use async/await, but I need to execute the `handleOpen` after todos are on the screen. Do you know any ways to do this?

Comment: They will be on the screen after first render. Why do you need to run this functions then?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to get some kind of call back once memoizedTodos are displayed on the screen.

The callback you are looking for is actually `useEffect` with empty dependency array.

> or execute handleOpen function once memoizedTodos are displayed on the screen.

`useEffect` will be invoked after the render, when `memoizedTodos` are already rendered.

The order: `useMemo -> render -> useEffect`

So all you actually need is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("this is running");
}, []);
```

Comment: Do I need `memoizedTodos` in the dependency array?

Comment: Sorry you said empty dependency array

Comment: @tomo1234 Definitely not, you are not using`memoizedTodos` in the `useEffect` nor referring to it.

Comment: So the example above is a really small number of objects so displaying these on the screen won't take a while but imagine you have thousands of todos and want to wait until all of the todos are on the screen. Can I run a function after this happens?

Comment: @tomo1234 Even if there's one million of todos it will still render before `useEffect`.

Comment: I think I used `render` the wrong way sorry for this. So I edited my questions but I'd like to wait until all of the todos are displaying on the screen like I can see all of them visibly and after that I like to run `handleOpen`. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect with `memoizedTodos` as dependency like this

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('this is a callbak')
  },[memoizedTodos])
```

- every time your `memoizedTodos` change the useEffect will be executed
- also the useEffect is execute after the render
- render is produced by memoized change (you have your callback)